# How do I divide .VOB files into separate videos?

Tags: video, vlc, dvd

I have a SONY Handycam that uses minidiscs as storage for videos. While on the camera menu and through VLC I'm able to see all the videos I recorded if I open the entire folder and not just the files. But instead of the 14 videos I shot there are only 3 files and the videos are joined together in 3 different .vob files which correspond to each page in the dvd menu.

So my question is, how do I separate each video? Is there a recommendation for a program that can help me out? can I do it with VLC?

Thanks!